# Having two tax rates with same percent but different names

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.6, magento-1.8, tax, magento-1.5

I'm struggeling with this for a few days now.

I'm trying to sell products and insurances. Products have 19% VAT, insurances have 19% insurance tax.

I added a new Tax class, rate and rule.

[image]

If I see this correct, magento aggregates taxes with the same rate. There is no way to prevent this (at least I didn't found one)

```
\Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Tax::_totalBaseCalculation()
```

It doesn't matter what priority my rules has.

I'm ending with this, which is correct calculated, but not splitted in the correct parts:

```
MwSt. (19%)      21,70 $
Vst. (19%)       21,70 $
Tax              21,70 $
```

After adding shipping, it looks like this, now the sums are totally screwed:

```
MwSt. (19%)      22,50 $
Vst. (19%)       21,70 $
Tax              22,50 $
```

The interessting part is, the invoice in the backend is again ok (the pdf too):

```
Shipping & Handling Tax   0,80 $
MwSt. (19%)              15,97 $
Vst. (19%)                5,73 $
Total Tax                22,50 $
```

At the moment I think magento can't handle two different taxes with the same percent rate. At first glance, this use case isn't needed, but this evaluation is wrong :-/

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Quick idea: Without getting much into this you could lookup
`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/total/tax.phtml:33`
and see that there is `$row['amount']` used.
Try instead `$row['base_amount']` or `$row['base_real_amount']` as set in `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Resource/Calculation.php:159`.

Comment: Can you confirm if the calculations are wrong in both the display AND the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current answer is: There is no way to have two tax settings with the same rate at the same time in the cart. The tax sum is always wrong.

In the invoice the calculation is correct...

Comment: This is possible or not, that we apply two tax rules in a single product in cart, like below example

http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11366/13832

http://www.screencast.com/t/JzhonL6L

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.8  can't reproduce the issue.

Cart page: http://screencast.com/t/JzhonL6L

Checkout page: http://screencast.com/t/IhVCQjOJD6Q

Looks like as you want. Please contact with me, I think you have issues with configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look on it and compare the code. Didn't tried it :-(

Comment: Did you define two tax rates on the same product? I can reproduce my problem in 1.8, Would be great if you can send me a few screenshots of your tax settings so I can check magento-stackexchange@fabian-blechschmidt.de

Comment: But your tax is two times 19% I need two products, one with 19% VAT and one with 19% VST. The first product 100$ and 19$ VAT and the second 10$ with 1.9$ insurance tax. Sums up to 110$ and 20.9$ tax. In your example there are ~38% tax.

Answer (score 0):

What country (is this common in Europe)?  Why would you want a separate summary for insurance tax ( to remit for a refund or legal requirement )?  I haven't tried yet - but have you tried CE 1.8.1; set a product tax class = Insurance;  create an insurance rate/zone;  create a tax rule (product tax class = Insurance; with insurance rate/zone;  set sort to 1; select checkbox for calculate of sub-total).  Does that work?

Comment: No didn't check it, just finished the project as "unsolvable" but I'll try. Why all this? Because the insurance tax doesn't count as "input VAT"(?) and therefore we need to account it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

We see a similar issue

Suddenly there are 2 tax rates (whilst both are really 21%). Mage 1.8.1

[image]