# Apply two tax rates with different percent on a single product in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, tax-class

We want to apply two tax rules(tax and vat) on a single product in cart.  Like below image. I have created tax class with two tax rules but it's always use 1 in cart. I got this image from

[Having two tax rates with same percent but different names](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/having-two-tax-rates-with-same-percent-but-different-names)

But not getting my solutions.

Thanks in advance

[image]